# Php generated Query show error in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
select student.studentID, invoice.invoiceID, student.name,  
MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(invoice.month, '%m')) as Month, invoice.tuitionfee as 'Total Amount', payment.tuitionpaid
from invoice 
join student
left join payment
on invoice.studentID = student.studentID and invoice.invoiceID = payment.invoiceID
where invoice.`create_date` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) and student.studentID = '28' group by invoice.month
```

The above query can run and give me the required result as i want but in phpmyadmin only

the question is this that when i put this query in my php code (codeigniter) and the model generated query is not running i don't know what to do please help me

PHP code

```
public function get_month_wise_dues($id){
    $this->db->select("student.studentID, 
    invoice.invoiceID, student.name, 
    MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(invoice.month, '%m')) as Month, 
    invoice.tuitionfee as 'Total Amount', payment.tuitionpaid");
    $this->db->from('invoice');
    $this->db->join('student','invoice.studentID = student.studentID');
    $this->db->join('payment','invoice.invoiceID = payment.invoiceID','LEFT');
    $this->db->where('invoice.`create_date` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) and student.studentID=', $id);
    $this->db->group_by('invoice.month');
    $this->db->order_by('invoice.month', 'asc'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    // echo $this->db->last_query();
    // exit;
    return $query->result();}
```

This is php generated Query

```
SELECT `student`.`studentID`, `invoice`.`invoiceID`, `student`.`name`, MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(invoice.month, `'%m'))` as Month, `invoice`.`tuitionfee` as 'Total Amount', `payment`.`tuitionpaid`
FROM (`invoice`)
JOIN `student` ON `invoice`.`studentID` = `student`.`studentID`
LEFT JOIN `payment` ON `invoice`.`invoiceID` = `payment`.`invoiceID`
WHERE `invoice`.`create_date` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) and 
student.studentID= '28'
GROUP BY `invoice`.`month`
ORDER BY `invoice`.`month` asc
```

When i run the php generated query it didn't give me the required result as the first query mentioned

Error is given below

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM (`invoice`) JOIN `student` ON `invoice`.`studentID` =
>   `student`.`studentID`' at line 2

Comment: in the call to `select` add second argument false, ie `$this->db->select('....', FALSE);`

Comment: thanks a lot ... its worked  Ilya Bursov

Comment: Is there a framework or ORM involved here? It's not listed but this code looks like it uses one.

Comment: @tadman codeigniter is mentioned

Comment: @IlyaBursov Thanks, tagged accordingly so this gets the right attention.

Comment: Ok i will do it next time ... its my first time in stackoverflow .... @IlyaBursov . one thing more how i will vote your comment which was very useful for me